# Why I got derivedETH=0 on Uniswap V3 for token query in theGraph?

Tags: graphql, ethereum, web3js, web3py, uniswap

Here is CHEQ/USDT token 0xa305f3aad48e285c002a2dbadbbba58fea10ad45 on Uniswap V3

On all screeners I see current price is 0.1137 USDT (like https://dexscreener.com/ethereum/0xa305f3aad48e285c002a2dbadbbba58fea10ad45).

Playground to check: https://thegraph.com/hosted-service/subgraph/uniswap/uniswap-v3

The problem is I'm getting derivedETH=0 on almost any block (only on blocks around 18631700 it's not 0), although it does **not equal zero. Why? How can I get current price in USD or ETH with graph?**

```
{
  token(id: "0x70edf1c215d0ce69e7f16fd4e6276ba0d99d4de7") {
      id
      symbol
      name
      decimals
      totalSupply
      volume
      volumeUSD
      untrackedVolumeUSD
      totalValueLocked
      feesUSD
      txCount
      derivedETH
  }
  bundles(first: 5) {
    id
    ethPriceUSD
  }
}
```

Okey, let's try pool request (0xa305f3aad48e285c002a2dbadbbba58fea10ad45 is pair contract):

```
{
    pool(id: "0xa305f3aad48e285c002a2dbadbbba58fea10ad45") {
        tick
        token0 {
            symbol
            id
            decimals
            derivedETH
            txCount
        }
        token1 {
            symbol
            id
            decimals
            derivedETH
            txCount
        }
        feeTier
        sqrtPrice
        liquidity
    }
}
```

Result has also `"derivedETH": "0"`

```
{
  "data": {
    "pool": {
      "tick": "-90820",
      "token0": {
        "symbol": "CHEQ",
        "id": "0x70edf1c215d0ce69e7f16fd4e6276ba0d99d4de7",
        "decimals": "9",
        "derivedETH": "0",
        "txCount": "6827"
      },
      "token1": {
        "symbol": "USDT",
        "id": "0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7",
        "decimals": "6",
        "derivedETH": "0.0002559071351455432255621805254727805",
        "txCount": "6869581"
      },
      "feeTier": "3000",
      "sqrtPrice": "844988916207015749935427513",
      "liquidity": "46412668995545"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the graph has a minimum required amount of eth for the pool to be tracked, did you verify it meets the requirements?  I believe its in the `prices.ts` file off the top of my head I think its 60 ETH?  Also looks like a lot of market manipulation and fake traffic to that coin.